# Free SQLite equivalent of the Visual Database Design found in MySQL's Workbench, for linux

Tags: database, sqlite

I really liked working with the Visual Database Designer in MySQL workbench. In my current project I'm looking for something equivalent. However, the ones that I found are either commercial or only for windows.

Is there an equivalent to MySQL's Visual Database Design for SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the Firefox [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) plugin?

It's not as complex as the MySQL tool but is relatively lightweight and cross-platform.

Comment: I can't find a visual database designer in that plugin although it is a very nice tool.

Comment: This is my go-to software for anything SQLite related.

Comment: This answer does not address the question at all.

Comment: @Jfly - in the sense that this was accepted as the answer by the OP, your objection (and, I think, downvote) seems a bit unreasonable